# How to make changes in a Docker container if it is not running

Tags: docker

I am working with a postgresql container, however there was a syntax error in a configuration file, when I restarted it, it is not running. How can I rectify the syntax error and get docker container running again?

Earlier I used `docker exec -it containerid bash` to enter into the terminal and made changes to the file.

Comment: if the configuration file is not part of a volume or a bind mount, you need to rebuild the image and re-create the container

Comment: Is the config file on a volume or mount? If so you can just fix it there, and then restart the container.

Comment: Run `docker inspect container_name` and then search for `overlay/diff` files, find the incorrect file, correct it and now you can run it properly. But it's not advised to manually edit files

Comment: I have no idea if that file is on a volume or a mount , but i even when i rebuild it , it is not working

Comment: Containers should follow the 'cattle, not pets' idea. If there's something wrong with a container, you get a new one. I.e. build a new image with the correct configuration and run that. You don't fix a broken container.

Comment: hi People, Since it was a windows Operating system i managed to view the files in docker desktop. thank you for the help